# How to delete imported photos and videos from my iPhone 5c

Tags: data-synchronization, iphone

I synced photos and videos from my PC to my iPhone 5c using iTunes. I need space on the phone so I tried deleting them. I can select them just fine but the trashcan icon is dull. Normally it is lit up and I can delete photos or videos, but now i can't. I've tried going on iTunes, clicking the phone, selecting the photo icon, unchecking the sync box, and it says that they are deleted but they are still on the phone taking up 6.7 GB of data. I still can't delete them. I can select but I can't delete, even on the PC. What do i do?

Comment: this may be a photo stream issue.  Pics are saved to your photo stream and then age out.  I don't know how to clean that out, may the Google be with you

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a PC guy but usually your photos live in iTunes Media Library.
Whatever method you can use to find it, you delete your photos from there.
Usually just use your search function on your PC to find the iTunes folder, open it until you find the iTunes Media Folder and delete whatever files you don't need to have synced.

After you delete your photos (Or just move them to another location if you're afraid you may loose them), you must sync your phone to iTunes again and this will refresh your iPhone's list of songs and photos, revealing more space.
After this is done, find the option on iTunes to not sync your iPhone when connected and either manage your files manually or resync when your storage problem is fixed (a new phone with larger storage, for example).
Your original photos are still in your PC, unless you deleted the originals.